# Angular-google-maps Get markers Coordinates to draw Polyline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to draw a line with polyline using angular-google-maps [(doc here)](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).

I'm not very familiar with AngularJS so I've got some difficuties to do what I want to do.

I'am able to print markers on the map with this function :

```
function addPosition (position, refresh) {
  if (! _.mHas(position, "longitude", "latitude", "username")) {
    console.log("That's not a proper position entry !");
    return;
  }
  if (position.latitude === '' || position.longitude === '' ) return;
  vm.map.markers.push({
    id : vm.map.markers.length,
    coords : {
      longitude : position.longitude,
      latitude : position.latitude
    },
    name : position.username,
    options : {
      icon : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
      draggable : false
    }
  });

  if (refresh) {
    $timeout(function () {
      vm.map.control.refresh();
    }, 5);
  }
}
```

I want to draw a Polyline between my markers but I don't have the good logic to take all coordinates from my markers and create a path with them.
I know I have to do something like :

```
function userLocation (position){
  var lat = position.latitude;
  var lng = position.longitude;
  var pathLine = [new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)];}
```

And then draw the Polyline with something like this:

```
$scope.polylines = [{
        path: pathLine,
        stroke: {
            color: '#000000',
            weight: 3
          },
          editable: false,
          draggable: false,
          geodesic: true,
          visible: true,
        }];
```

With my "logic" i'm stuck in concept where I get coordinates forEach markers and it give me path results with : coordinates of my first marker and coordinates NULL, and , NULL coordinates and coordinates of my second marker.

I've created a JSFiddle with the code if you need [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ny5qt2hb/3/), without the $scope.Polyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are utilizing [`angular-google-maps` library](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) and want

> to draw a Polyline between my markers but I don't have the good logic
>   to take all coordinates from my markers and create a path with them.

and given that data for markers is represented in the following format:

```
[
   {
       id : vm.map.markers.length,
       coords : {
          longitude : position.longitude,
          latitude : position.latitude
       },
       name : position.username,
       options : {
          icon : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
          draggable : false
       }
    }
    //...
]
```

data for *Polyline* could be generated like this:

```
vm.map.polyline = vm.map.markers.map(m => m.coords);
```

Example

```js
angular
  .module("mapApp", ["uiGmapgoogle-maps"])
  .controller("mapCtrl", function($scope) {
      vm = this;
    vm.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: -24.9923319,
        longitude: 125.2252427
      },
      zoom: 4,
      lineStyle: {
        color: "#333",
        weight: 5,
        opacity: 0.7
      },


      markers : [
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -33.8473567,
            longitude: 150.6517955
          },
          name: "Sydney",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -37.9716929,
            longitude: 144.772958
          },
          name: "Melbourne",
          id: 3
        },
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -34.9998826,
            longitude: 138.3309812
          },
          name: "Adelaide",
          id: 4
        },
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -32.0391738,
            longitude: 115.6813556
          },
          name: "Perth",
          id: 5
        },
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -12.425724,
            longitude: 130.8632684
          },
          name: "Darwin",
          id: 6
        },
        {
          coords: {
            latitude: -16.8801503,
            longitude: 145.5768602
          },
          name: "Cairns",
          id: 7
        }
      ],

    };

    vm.map.polyline = vm.map.markers.map(m => m.coords);


  });
```

```css
.angular-google-map-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/2.0.X/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl as vm"> 
        <ui-gmap-google-map 
          center='vm.map.center' 
          zoom='vm.map.zoom'>
          <ui-gmap-markers models="vm.map.markers" coords="'coords'" idkey="'id'" ></ui-gmap-markers>
          <ui-gmap-polyline path="vm.map.polyline" draggable="false" geodesic="true" stroke="vm.map.lineStyle" fit="false"></ui-gmap-polyline>
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vadim, it helped me a lot !!

Comment: For people not very familiar with angular, the symbol "=>" is an arrow function. It can be write like this:
  vm.map.polyline = vm.map.markers.map(function(m){
        return m.coords
      });